# Alternate text of div

Tags: php, wordpress, html, alt

Can i put class name in title of div? It's possible?

```
<div class="flag brasileña" title="phpcode"></div>
```

I want put in title, text of second class "brasileña" with php code or similar

Comment: This won't do anything. What do you want to achieve, a browser tooltip?

Comment: similar, yes... i want that someone put mouse over flag div, show text of second class

Comment: @vektor What is the 'text of the second class'? Just write: `<div class="flag brasilena" alt="brasilena"></div>`.

Comment: jeje ok, but this second class is dynamic. i can´t put that. don't worry, maybe i'll create a custom field and array it!

Comment: and sorry, i don't want alt, in div is title=""

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php 
$className = "flag brasileña";
$alt = explode(" ", $className);
?>

<div class='<?php echo $className ?>' title='<?php echo $alt[1] ?>'></div>
```

Assuming class name always has two words and alt always take the second word and since you mentioned you want to do it by php the class name is generated dynamically.

This is how you can do it but this wont serve any purpose.
Whats that you want to do with adding second word to "alt".

Comment: @vektor are 96 flags stored into database? if yes loop through the result.